# Excel Vsto Application is not properly work in Excel 2016

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Excel 2016 64 bit gives following Error

> Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE
>   action.

I already installed all preriquisites like vsto 4.0 , PIA etc Also installed supporting .Net framework . Application is developed and build using Office 2007 and Visual Studio 2008 + C# .

So please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addin for office 2007 created with VS 2008 will not be compatible with office 2016, please refer to this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx) for more detail.

Comment: what is solution to develop office + vsto application in office 2016

Comment: create addin with VS2010 or latter

Comment: but it is not installed

Comment: there is 90 day free trial of vs2015 you may download and see if you can make it work

Comment: bhaiya, I was already Tried in VS2013 with Office 2016 installed and vsto 4.0 and PIA for office 2010  but it is not working that is showing massage as "Cannot Create the project because the application associated with this project type is not installed on this computer. You must install the Microsoft office application that is associated with this project type"

Comment: I would suggest you create another thread for this because the situation is now different and is related to migration. you may also check this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a9965f68-e550-44be-8e2e-4a25d16030c1/vsto-project-wizards-fails-with-cannot-create-the-project-because-the-application-associated-with?forum=vsto

Comment: Remain to check on visual Studio 2015 after  checking it I will update you sir .

Comment: after installing vs2015 installer build from office 2007 is working Properly on Issued System

Answer (score -1):

If you go in to Excel - File - Options - Advanced and tick Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE) that should fix it.

[image]

You can read more about DDE [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648774(v=vs.85).aspx)

There's possibly a way to do this with a regedit that Grey found. It's ticked as answered but the question has been closed. Here's the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607165/how-do-i-programmatically-change-advanced-excel-options-in-c-sharp)

Comment: After applying that also it is showing same error .

Comment: Do you have any add-ins in Excel?

Comment: no addin for that application this is just excel workbook application